# Googlebot and Google Mobile bot Crawl Error after Domain IP and Domain DNS changed (Site not Reachable)

Tags: dns, seo, digital-ocean, google-search

in past week I had to change my server to cloud (Digital Ocean Droplet), I am using a shared service but the concurrent user reached the number of Php execution (30). I shifted the entire site and site is up and running successfully, moreover Yandex and Bing are able to crawl my website but it is Google that I want.
I have got like 100K errors in console dashboard and raising, google ads bot isn't able to crawl my pages too. I have checked the following and there is no error in these.

1. .htaccess and redirections.
2. SSL
3. DNS records (I shifted name servers to DO and then back to registrar to see if the DNS was the error) but it doesn't seem like it is.
4. I double checked robots.txt it is fine by the google robots.txt validator and other search engines.
5. Similar setups are running on other servers with no changes at all the are fine.
6. UfW, I am new to it but due to its temporary nature I don't think it is the reason. I disabled it and checked it doesn't make difference.
7. I haven't blocked anything on apache so it should be good too.

The error that appears is attached at screenshots

[image: Search Console Live Test]

[image: Google Mobile Friendly Test]

Help me out as instead of scaling, I am going down bad.

Answer (score 0):

I repointed the DNS through another service it took its time but it is resolved. I wasn't sure about the error, now I am, it is because of improper or partial DNS resolution issue.